# JavaScript function local variable being accessed globally

Tags: javascript, closures

Below is from a textbook that I am working through, but something doesn't make sense. Can someone please explain to me how I'm able to access the local variable "secret" from the global scope? When I run the code the output is '100'. I thought that variables declared inside of a function can't be accessed from outside the function. What is happening here that I can set "secret" to 100?

```
    var set, get;

    function val() {
        var secret = 0;

        set = function (arg) {
            if (typeof(arg) === "number") {
                secret = arg;   
            }
        };

        get = function () {
            return secret;
        };
    }

    secret = 100;

    document.write(secret);
```

output > 100

---

By the way, the textbook originally has the function as an immediate function. I changed to the above hoping that it would lead to a different outcome.

Comment: You may want to read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You have a global **and** a local `secret` variable.

```
// Creating a global variable, not affecting the one inside val
secret = 100;
// This is accessing the global variable
document.write(secret);
```

If you actually run your `val` function, you'll see that they are different

```js
 var set, get;

 function val() {
   var secret = 0;

   set = function(arg) {
     if (typeof(arg) === "number") {
       secret = arg;
     }
   };

   get = function() {
     return secret;
   };
 }

val();

secret = 100;
document.write("global secret = " + secret + '<br />');
set(5);
document.write("private secret = " + get() + '<br />');
document.write("global secret unaffected = " + secret + '<br />');
```